# Unexpected error when tyring to get the payment transactions of a user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I always get an error when tyring to get the payment transactions of a user.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2
  }
}
```

I tried several approaches:

```php
// approach 1
$response = $app['facebook']->api('/'.$app['user']['fbUserID'].'/payment_transactions', 'GET', [
    //'request_id' => $order['requestID'],
    'access_token' => $app['fb.app_id'].'|'.$app['fb.app_secret']
]);

// approach 2
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$app['user']['fbUserID'].'/payment_transactions?fields=id&access_token='.$app['fb.app_id'].'|'.$app['fb.app_secret'];

$ch = curl_init();
$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Expect:'),
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => DIR.'/vendor/facebook/php-sdk/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt'
];
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

// approach 3
// like 2 but with a fresh access token
$appAccessToken = explode('=', file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.$app['fb.app_id'].'&client_secret='.$app['fb.app_secret'].'&grant_type=client_credentials'))[1];
```

Even in the Graph API Explorer I get this error. Only if I use the commandline it works:

```
$ curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/........./payment_transactions?access_token=.......|.........'
```

The user is an test user which is also a payment tester and made successfull test-purchases. The Local Currency Payments Breaking Changes are disabled.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an app access token to GET from that endpoint. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#payment_transactions for details.